# Etimologia de "canga" (no sentido de ferramenta de arado)

Tags: etimologia, regionalismo

No Brasil, principalmente no nordeste, "*canga*" é o mesmo que "*jugo*" (do latim ["jugum"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iugum#Latin), mas creio que em Portugal chame-se ["parelha"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parelha)), uma ferramenta usada na cabeça dos bois para emparelhá-los durante o arado. Também há o termo "*cangalho*", que refere-se aos paus da canga que se ajustam ao pescoço do animal; e "*cangote*", que significa nuca.

[image: Uma canga (aka jugo).]

Eu achava que esses termos viriam do Tupi, porque *'canga* significa "cabeça" em [Tupi Clássico](http://www.dicionariotupiguarani.com.br/dicionario/canga/) e em [Tupi Antigo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/akanga#Tupinamb.C3.A1). Como o jugo é usado na cabeça dos animais, seria portanto plausível chamá-lo *canga*, dado o significado Tupi supracitado. "*Canga*", no Brasil, também é usado para se referir a empate "cabeça-a-cabeça" em jogos populares.

Porém, segundo [esse artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_vocabulary#List_of_Portuguese_words_of_Germanic_origin), "*canga*" veio do proto-celta "**cambĭca*" ou  "**cambĭta*"<sup>[1]</sup>, através das línguas celtas faladas na península ibérica antes da invasão romana. Esse artigo cita como fonte o [*Romanisches etymologisches Wörterbuch*](https://archive.org/stream/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft#page/118/mode/1up) (em alemão, "Dicionário Etimológico Românico"). 
<sup>[1]</sup>: Teria ["*cambito*"](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/cambito) vindo também dessa mesma origem?

Já este [Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa](https://archive.org/stream/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/DicionarioEtimolgicoDaLinguaPortuguesa#page/n133/mode/2up) propõe também outras fontes, como potenciais fontes chinesas/cantonesas. Nesse caso, "canga" originaria-se de uma ferramenta de punição corporal que prende a pessoa pela cabeça.

Os dicionários [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=BlDO) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/canga) simplesmente dizem que a etimologia é desconhecida e controversa, respectivamente.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- De onde vem o termo "canga" como ferramenta de arado?
- Estes termos (canga, cangalho e cangote) são também usados popularmente fora do Brasil (preferencialmente em alguma região de Portugal ou da Galícia)?
- Se o termo for de origem chinesa ou tupi, os registros desse termo devem ser recentes (i.e., contemporâneo ou posterior à era das navegações). Mas se for de origem latina ou celta, ele deve aparecer em registros antigos pré-navegação, certo? Só assim se descarta as hipóteses de origem além-mar (Brasil e China).
- Se o termo for de origem celtíbera, provavelmente as demais línguas da península ibérica e do sul da França (Galego, Espanhol, Catalão, Galês, Occitano etc.) devem também ter a mesma palavra ou cognatos. Há? (Não consegui encontrar nenhum).
- De onde vem o "*cangote*" (nuca)?

Comment: *Canga* é a palavra que se usa na minha região, perto de Lisboa. *Jugo* é conhecido, mas é mais usado em sentido figurado, *sob o jugo* 'sob o domínio'. *Parelha* nunca ouvi nesse sentido, mas pode haver variação regional.

Comment: Para mim também, "canga" é o nome que conheço, do Douro e Minho. Jugo não conhecia com esse significado.

Comment: @Jacinto no Minho é "jugo" que se usa com mais frequência, embora nos dias de hoje já pouca gente conheça o objeto, só pessoas mais velhas a partir dos 30 anos...

Comment: @ANeves no Minho? Tens a certeza do que dizes? Eu nunca ouvi canga na minha vida.

Comment: @JorgeB. pelos visto tu e o ANeves andam por sítios diferentes do Minho.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil eu ouço bastante o termo canga das pessoas mais velhas e de zonas rurais, tanto como ferramenta, quanto em topónimos e expressões de origem indígena, e em termos relacionados ao cangaço.

Comment: @JorgeB. O Minho é muito grande! :) Na aldeola da minha avó, entre Viana e Ponte do Lima, é por "canga" que conheci isto.

Comment: O artigo sobre [parelha na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parelha) é confuso. Mas parece-me que no artigo *parelha* se refere aos dois bois e não à canga. De qualquer modo nunca ouvi em Portugal, ou noutro sítio, chamar *parelha* à canga; nem a dois bois; aqui há *parelhas* de cavalos ou burros e *juntas* de bois.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Canga*** existe de facto com significados relacionados em várias línguas ibéricas e está atestado em português bastante cedo, tornando improvável qualquer origem no Novo Mundo ou no Oriente.

É usado comumente em Portugal e existe também em galego com o mesmo significado [(Real Academia Galega)](http://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/canga). Na minha limitada experiência serve mais frequentemente para atrelar os bois a um carro do que a um arado (ver foto abaixo). Em asturiano *canga* é também apetrecho do mesmo tipo, mas pelos vistos prende ao peito [(Diccionario General de la Lengua Asturiana)](http://mas.lne.es/diccionario/palabra/6639). Em castelhano, *canga* tem significados relacionados: é um arado ou, na Andaluzia, uma parelha de quaisquer animais exceto, curiosamente, bois [(Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=77tAirX%7C77tKJCw%7C77zG84s).

Pelo menos em português, *canga* e o derivado *cangalha* estão atestadas muito cedo:

- Temos *canga* no século XIV, mas numa aceção diferente, ‘armação de madeira usada sobre telhados de palha’ (Houaiss, 2003).
- [*Cangalha* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cangalha), com vários significados relacionados a *canga*, está atestado em 1518 (Houaiss). Isto é depois da chegada dos portugueses ao Brasil, mas antes do início a sério da colonização do Brasil; é também uns meros cinco anos depois da chegada dos Portugueses a Macau. E *canga* teria de existir já antes de *cangalha*.
- O primeiro exemplo de *canga de bois* que consegui encontrar é de 1562, no dicionário de Jerónimo Cardoso [(Corpus do Português), e temos aqui um fac-simile do mesmo texto na [edição de 1570 do *Dicictionarium Lusitanicolatinum* do mesmo autor](http://purl.pt/14265/3/#/578).

Portanto, mesmo que admitamos (improvavelmente, na minha opinião) que os sentidos ‘armação de madeira usada sobre telhados de palha’ e ‘armação de madeira usada sobre o cachaço dos bois’ têm origens diferentes, 1518 e mesmo 1562 parecem-me cedo demais para que uma palavra tupi significando ‘cabeça’ adquirisse um significado diferente, viesse para Portugal, competindo com outra palavra já existente [(*jugo*)](http://www.aulete.com.br/jugo), e entrasse num dicionário. Além disso temos também a existência da palavra noutras línguas ibéricas.

O dicionário Houaiss diz que segundo os filólogos Antenor Nascentes e Antônio Geraldo da Cunha este*canga* vem provavelmente do céltico **cambica* ‘madeira curva’, o que se ajusta às duas aceções, ‘canga do telhado de palha’ e ‘canga dos bois’. O [dicionário da Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=77tAirX%7C77tKJCw%7C77zG84s) diz o mesmo.

O que terá origem oriental, ainda segundo Antenor Nascentes e Antônio Geraldo da Cunha (Houaiss) é [*canga* (Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/canga) na aceção de ‘instrumento de suplício chinês’. Nomeadamente Antônio Geraldo da Cunha indica como origem o chinês *kang-kia* ou o anamita (do Vietname) *gong*, que teriam na passagem ao português sofrido influência de *canga* nas aceções anteriores.

Novamente segundo o Houaiss, *cangote* é uma modificação de *cogote*, com influência de *canga*. E *cogote* é castelhano, atestado em 1490, significando [(ERA)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9g5JsLR) ‘parte superior e posterior do pescoço; penacho que se colocava no capacete na zona do cogote’.

---

Para não ficar atrás do Seninha, aqui fica uma foto de família, por volta de 1970-75, uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa. À direita, o meu avô, um tio meu à esquerda com o aguilhão, e primos empoleirados no carro. Creio que eu não estou lá.
[image]

Comment: @Seninha, sim, é uma grande coincidência. Mas segundo o Houaiss, *canga* não existe como cabeça em português, mas *-acanga* entr com essa noção na formação de palavras. Vou citar: "**-canga**  *el. comp.* pospositivo do tupi *kanga*, 'espinha, osso, suporte forte, sustentáculo', em palavras de várias épocas depois do descobrimento do Brasil: *anijuacanga, boioçupecanga* [etc.]; com *-acanga*, seu der., há a noção de 'cabeça', em *jacareacanga, tapanhoacanga*, e tb. em *acangapara, acangapema* [etc.]" No verbete *acangapara* ('cágado') e outros, diz que vem do tupi *a'kanga* 'cabeça'. >>

Comment: >> Quanto à *canga* "chinesa", se for como diz o A.G. Cunha, é mais um caso de uma palavra portuguesa passar a designar também um objeto estrangeiro que tinha um nome na língua original e uma função algo parecidas com a *canga* já existente.

Comment: Estava dando uma olhada nas palavras de origem celtíbera, e muitas delas ou são de contexto rural, ou são relativos a algum elemento do campo, ou são termos usados hoje pelos anciãos em cidades mais tradicionais. O que faz sentido, já que antes da colonização romana a região era dominada por povos mais rurais.

Comment: Já na minha, também limitada, experiência, ouvi canga indo muito além do sentido de emparelhar bois a um carro/arado. Meu avô chama de canga um pedaço de pau colocado sobre os ombros de um único porco (em vez de sobre um par de bois) para evitar que ele fuja por entre as frestas da cerca do chiqueiro.  Aliás, a [Wikipedia galega](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xugo#Xugo_de_canga) refere-se a canga como sendo um tipo específico de jugo (em vez de um sinônimo).

Comment: @Seninha, eu vi essa aceção de canga nos dicionários, mas nunca vi nenhuma. Ninguém na minha família tinha porcos.

Comment: @Seninha, mesmo em Portugal há variação regional: [aqui em Monsanto, Beira Baixa](http://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/6083/16/ulsd053285_td_CORDIAL_SIN_mst_n.pdf), a peça de madeira que assenta no cachaço é *canga*, e *jugo* é uma alternativa com o mesmo fim mas agarra aos cornos, mais opressor, apropriado para gado mais bravo, que conseguiria fugir da canga. O [artigo da Wikipédia que indicaste](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parelha) faz distinção parecida, mas a justificação é diferente, jugo para carga leve, canga para pesada, sugerindo que os modelos não são bem iguais aos de Monsanto

Comment: @Seninha, o assunto tem sido debatido também aqui no [Falatório, chat do site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio).

Comment: Todas essas variações são relacionadas ao emparelhamento de gado. Quanto à aceção de bloquear a passagem dum animal por passagens estreitas só vi no galego, os cognatos de outras línguas parece não ter esse sentido. E nem sabia que aqui tinha chat.

Comment: @Seninha, afinal eu vi foi *cangalha* = Triângulo de madeira que se põe no pescoço dos porcos para impedir que fucem canteiros e plantações [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cangalha).

Comment: @Jacinto, quando partilhas uma ligação para o chat deixa sempre uma ligação não para a sala em si, mas para uma linha do chat/transcript. Que assim no futuro dá para ir ao mesmo sítio reler a conversa. :)

Comment: E um uso de jugo "in the wild": https://www.publico.pt/2018/09/19/p3/cronica/conjuge-1844551 «E, mais simples ainda, “jugo”, que é uma coisa lá do campo, lá da terra dos avós ou dos primos afastados (atrasados?), ou das histórias da carochinha, só se conhece como adereço para autenticar uma parcela de monte em que se construiu um barraco de férias e a que se procura dar o toque rural autêntico.»

Comment: @ANeves, e como é que eu faço isso? Andei lá a ver e o endereço parece ser sempre o mesmo.

Comment: @Jacinto no lado esquerdo de uma linha, tem uma seta triangular para baixo. Abres essa janeluca, e tem um "permalink" - que é uma hiperligação para a transcrição da sala de chat. E.g.: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39081283#39081283

Comment: @ANeves, fixe, já percebi.

Answer (score -1):

Em inglês é kanga. O termo pode ser visto neste vídeo https://youtu.be/oI4wLFneHno?t=91

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/6253)

Comment: Marcelo, bem-vindo ao site. A "kanga" que o video mostra é o instrumento de suplício chinês (que também é *canga* em português), não é a canga (jugo) dos bois.